# why do I need the curly braces here?

Tags: c

Consider this simple program:

`fails.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                            

int main(){                                                   
    int i = 10;                                                                                         
    if (i == 10)                                          
        int j = 11;                                                                                         
    return 0;        
}
```

That fails to compile (`gcc fails.c`), giving this error:

```
fails.c: In function ‘main’:
fails.c:7:3: error: expected expression before ‘int’
   int j = 11;
   ^
```

But this one goes through just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 10;
    if (i == 10){
        int j = 11;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I figured that the work around, is to put those `{}` in. But I wish to know why this is required.

Why does it behave this way, when something like `printf` is acceptable?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 10;
    if (i == 10)
        printf("some text\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Declaring a variable as the only statement in its scope makes no sense.

Comment: This is a great question. Made so because the answer is a bit intricate, and kinda neat.

Comment: Always use braces - stops you getting caught with your trousers down

Comment: Interestingly, this is legal in C++ (because C++ syntactically treats a declaration as a kind of statement, unless it's at file scope).

Comment: @SLaks "Declaring a variable as the only statement in its scope makes no sense." is true yet OP has nicely made a _minimal_ [MCVE] to exhibit the issue - a good thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `if` must be followed by a statement:

[C99/6.8.4](https://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#6.8.4)

> if ( expression ) statement

However, a [declaration](https://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#6.7) is **not** a statement:

[C99/6.8](https://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#statement)

> statement:
>
> labeled-statement
>
> compound-statement
>
> expression-statement
>
> selection-statement
>
> iteration-statement
>
> jump-statement

When put inside a `{}`, it is a compound-statement, thus ok.

Comment: I think you can improve the answer even more if you point out where a declaration is specified as a grammatical element (solidifying it as different to a statement).

Comment: @StoryTeller I think the point is that a declaration is not either of labeled-statement, ..., jump-statement. I'm not sure whether include the quotation of declaration itself will improve the answer...

Comment: Because there is nothing in the answer currently that would hint at `compound-statement` or `expression-statement` not being expandable to a declaration. You aren't just writing an answer for language lawyers, novices will read it as well. The more people can understand it, the better.

Comment: @StoryTeller OK, I added a link of declaration for interested reader to check.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between *declaration* and *statement*.

```
int j = 11;
```

is a declaration. `if` statement shall be followed by a statement. Putting `{}` after `if` statement results in a compound statement. A compound statement can have no other statement in it or can have a declaration.

Comment: C doesn't have anything called a "declaration statement". Declarations and statements are entirely disjoint. A compound statement consists of `{` followed by zero or more statements and/or declarations followed by `}`. (C90 requires all the declarations to precede all the declarations; C99 and C11 allow them to be mixed.) (C++ has different rules.) I suggest deleting the last word of your answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson; I agreed there is noting like "declaration statement" in C standard. My apologies that I just overlooked my answer before posting it. It wasn't intentional. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you compile your ANSI C code with C89 standard. And, unlike his successor C99, it requires all variables to be declared at the beginning of the scope. So, having `int j = 11;` somewhere in-between other statements just contradicts that C89 rule. If you open a new scope just before that `int j = 11;`, it's back to OK.

Actual reason of such C89 limitation should be an attempt to simplify memory management for stack-allocable variables. For instance, compare it with Pascal language that requires all variables to be declared in the special `var` section before the code (so, it's even more strict that C89).